# Hanami, show 'post' controller/view

Tags: ruby, hanami, hanami-model

I don't understand Hanami, I've created Message model, and I want to pull from DB message by `params[:id]`. The way we do it in Rails `@message = Message.find(params[:id]`.

I read documentation, and what I did after. My Controller (for show):

```
def call(params)
  @message = MessageRepository.find(params[:id])
end
```

And my erb:

```
<%= @message.title %>
```

But it gives me error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/hanami/controller#exposures

Comment: i've already try, but still gives me NilClass error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the controller call `expose :message`, then you can use it in the view or in the template as local variable (without the `@`).